# CSS specificity based on proximity to element instead of order in css code

Tags: html, css, sass, less, css-specificity

I have an ongoing issue where my css rules are jostling for control. Given this sass:

```
.green-theme {
    .theme-button {
        background: green;
    }
}

.blue-theme {
    .theme-button {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

and this html:

```
<div class="blue-theme">
    <div class="green-theme">
        <button class="theme-button">should be green</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My button is blue, because the blue-theme rule comes later in the css but I want it to be green as it is more closely nested to a .green-theme.

These themes are generated in sass so they are all the same. Is there a way I can flip this so it draws specificity from the proximity to the HTML element instead of order in the css file?

Comment: Are you meaning to say how to change how the code is processed without editing the code?

Answer (score 1):

For this specific use case, [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) help a lot.

```css
.blue-theme {
  --btn-color: blue;
}

.green-theme {
  --btn-color: green;
}

.theme-button {
  background: var(--btn-color);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-theme">
    <div class="green-theme">
        <button class="theme-button">should be green</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="green-theme">
    <div class="blue-theme">
        <button class="theme-button">should be blue</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

That said, the disjoint between the CSS definition order and the HTML hierarchy sounds like a significant code smell, but it's hard to make a recommendation without knowing more context.